# Sony SDK API Remote control Tutorial?

Tags: sdk, sony, remote-control, sony-camera-api

I'm planning to make a windows PC application to remote control my Sony (A5000) camera, to use for astrophotography with a telescope. I downloaded the API SDK package from Sony and I'm able to connect my camera (using the playmemory app on camera) to my laptop. But I seem to be missing a crucial piece of information how to proceed. I tried opening the sample app delivered by Sony in Netbeans, but I only get 100+ errors in the code. I have a basic understanding of Java programming, but I never did something like connecting to a piece of hardware. I noticed the tutorial on the Sony developer website, but that is way to 'scanty' to me. Does somebody know about a more detailed tutorial concerning this topic? I have the feeling that when I have the basic set-up (ie connection from app to camera and access to the methods (as documented in the SDK)), it won't be too difficult for me to make the app I need.

Additional info: I need to make an app that allows interval capturing WITH long exposures (more than 30 sec) in RAW and WITHOUT dark frames (Long exposure Noise Reduction).

Answer (score 1):

Cool project :-)

My particular language of choice is Python, and I have contributed to this project:
https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api

Since the example scripts are fairly self explanatory they might give you enough info to get going.

I do not believe that you can shoot/download raw images over the Sony Remote API (although I don't have a camera with raw ability to say for certain).
Simon.